# How to use ImmutableArray (C#) in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, immutability

I am trying to save ImmutableArray (System.Collections.Immutable) in MongoDB.

I tried MongoDB.Immutable but it is limited to old version of Immutable package, and doesn't support ImmutableArray.

I tried to create a custom serializer either using IBsonSerializer and IBsonSerializationProvider + SerializerBase without success.

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(BsonImmutableSerializer<>))]
public class BsonImmutableSerializer<T> : IBsonSerializer<ImmutableArray<T>>
{
    public Type ValueType => typeof(ImmutableArray<T>);

    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return context.Reader.ReadString().FromJson<ImmutableArray<T>>().ToImmutableArray();
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToJson());
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, ImmutableArray<T> value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToJson());
    }

    ImmutableArray<T> IBsonSerializer<ImmutableArray<T>>.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return context.Reader.ReadString().FromJson<ImmutableArray<T>>().ToImmutableArray();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ImmutableProvider<T> : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(ImmutableList<T>) ? new ImmutableSerializer<T>() : null;
    }
}

public class ImmutableSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<ImmutableList<T>>
{
    public override ImmutableList<T> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return context.Reader.ReadString().FromJson<List<T>>().ToImmutableList();
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, ImmutableList<T> value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToJson());
    }
}
```

The first solution throws this error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfint:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

The second one throws:

> System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[System.Int32]', on 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`2[TValue,TItem]' violates the constraint of type 'TValue'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[System.Int32]', on 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2[TValue,TItem]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TValue'.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would implement `EnumerableSerializerBase<TValue, TItem>`, but `TValue` is constrained to `class` and `ImmutableArray<T>` is a `struct`, so you need an implementation that can handle `struct`:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class ValueEnumerableSerializerBase<TValue, TItem> : SerializerBase<TValue>, IBsonArraySerializer, IBsonSerializer
    where TValue : struct, IEnumerable<TItem>
{
    private readonly Lazy<IBsonSerializer<TItem>> _lazyItemSerializer;

    protected ValueEnumerableSerializerBase()
        : this(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry)
    {
    }

    protected ValueEnumerableSerializerBase(IBsonSerializer<TItem> itemSerializer)
    {
        if (itemSerializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(itemSerializer));

        _lazyItemSerializer = new Lazy<IBsonSerializer<TItem>>(() => itemSerializer);
    }

    protected ValueEnumerableSerializerBase(IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
    {
        if (serializerRegistry == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializerRegistry));

        _lazyItemSerializer = new Lazy<IBsonSerializer<TItem>>(() => serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<TItem>());
    }

    public IBsonSerializer<TItem> ItemSerializer => _lazyItemSerializer.Value;

    public override TValue Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        IBsonReader reader = context.Reader;

        BsonType currentBsonType = reader.GetCurrentBsonType();
        switch (currentBsonType)
        {
            case BsonType.Null:
            {
                reader.ReadNull();
                return default;
            }
            case BsonType.Array:
            {
                reader.ReadStartArray();
                object accumulator = CreateAccumulator();
                while (reader.ReadBsonType() != BsonType.EndOfDocument)
                {
                    TItem item = _lazyItemSerializer.Value.Deserialize(context);
                    AddItem(accumulator, item);
                }
                reader.ReadEndArray();
                return FinalizeResult(accumulator);
            }
            default:
            {
                throw CreateCannotDeserializeFromBsonTypeException(currentBsonType);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TValue value)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        IBsonWriter writer = context.Writer;

        if (value.Equals(default))
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (TItem item in EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(value))
                _lazyItemSerializer.Value.Serialize(context, item);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetItemSerializationInfo(out BsonSerializationInfo serializationInfo)
    {
        IBsonSerializer<TItem> itemSerializer = _lazyItemSerializer.Value;
        serializationInfo = new BsonSerializationInfo(null, itemSerializer, itemSerializer.ValueType);
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract void AddItem(object accumulator, TItem item);

    protected abstract object CreateAccumulator();

    protected abstract IEnumerable<TItem> EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(TValue value);

    protected abstract TValue FinalizeResult(object accumulator);
}
```

From there, the implementation for `ImmutableArray<T>` is pretty straight-forward:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public class ImmutableArraySerializer<T> : ValueEnumerableSerializerBase<ImmutableArray<T>, T>, IChildSerializerConfigurable
{
    public ImmutableArraySerializer()
    {
    }

    public ImmutableArraySerializer(IBsonSerializer<T> itemSerializer)
        : base(itemSerializer)
    {
    }

    public ImmutableArraySerializer(IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
        : base(serializerRegistry)
    {
    }

    public IBsonSerializer WithItemSerializer(IBsonSerializer<T> itemSerializer)
    {
        return new ImmutableArraySerializer<T>(itemSerializer);
    }

    protected override void AddItem(object accumulator, T item)
    {
        ((ImmutableArray<T>.Builder)accumulator).Add(item);
    }

    protected override object CreateAccumulator()
    {
        return ImmutableArray.CreateBuilder<T>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<T> EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(ImmutableArray<T> value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    protected override ImmutableArray<T> FinalizeResult(object accumulator)
    {
        return ((ImmutableArray<T>.Builder)accumulator).ToImmutable();
    }

    IBsonSerializer IChildSerializerConfigurable.ChildSerializer => ItemSerializer;

    IBsonSerializer IChildSerializerConfigurable.WithChildSerializer(IBsonSerializer childSerializer)
    {
        return new ImmutableArraySerializer<T>((IBsonSerializer<T>)childSerializer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Work for me thanks.
Don't forget to declare the serializer :  BsonSerializer.RegisterGenericSerializerDefinition(typeof(ImmutableArray<>), typeof(ImmutableArraySerializer<>));